# Launch android Play Store app from PreferenceActivity?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

i am trying to launch **android Play Store**

from my **PreferenceActivity**.

Here is the code i tried to do that

in my `pref.xml` file

```
<Preference  android:key="rateus" android:title="See Android Market"></Preference>
```

in my java file

```
public class ExampleAppWidgetConfigure extends PreferenceActivity {

private int appWidgetId;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(
            widgetsharedpref.PREFS_NAME);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);

    Preference prefereces=findPreference("rateus");
    prefereces.setIntent(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.xyz.xyz")));


}
```

}

But when i run this and click on the Preference.

Nothing happens.

Whats wrong here??

Comment: Try
`Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:your.app.id"));
startActivity(intent);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not starting the market activity, it only creates an intent for starting it

Use this

```
Preference prefereces=findPreference("rateus");
preference.setOnPreferenceClickListener (new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener(){
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.xyz.xyz"));
        startActivity(intent);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

While vikki's answer works fine, here is yet simplified version of doing the same. It will simply launch the play store app with the specified app details.

```
<PreferenceScreen
    android:title="Rate My app on Play Store"
    android:summary="Please take a moment to rate our application and service on play store.">
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:data="market://details?id=com.abc.xyz" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

An alternate version is a bit more fail safe. Just replace `android:data` attribute with the original play store app link.

```
android:data="http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abc.xyz"
```

It basically  tries to load the playstore URL. This one works even if the play store application is not installed. The only problem is that, the installed browsers will be capturing the intent along with the play store app.